# Get YouTube Captions Displaying Automatically on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

We are translating our iOS app to Japanese and now need our Youtube video to have Japanese captions displayed automatically in our app. The following link works on the Chrome browser but when I open the same link on iOS with the chrome app the captions do not appear:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/z3oKRoGOlac?rel=0&hl=ja&cc_lang_pref=jacc_load_policy=1

Is there a work around for this? On our iOS app we have the link in an iFrame:

```
<body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe width=\"264\" height=\"153\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/z3oKRoGOlac?rel=0?version=3&hl=ja&cc_lang_pref=ja&cc_load_policy=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\

</body></html>
```

I also tried putting ?version=3 or ?version=2 in the url but that does not show the captions either.

--- Update

I just tried installing the youtube api to the app in xcode and the captions are not appearing on this one either. Here is my code:

```
    NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                             @"cc_load_policy" : @1,
                             @"hl" : @"ja"
                             };

[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"nAyw6GOUMlc" playerVars:playerVars];
```

-- 2nd Update

Found that captions only work when video is playing inline. This is the setting I used to get the video to work:

```
    NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                             @"fs" : @1,
                             @"controls" : @0,
                             @"playsinline" : @1,
                             @"showinfo" : @0,
                             @"cc_load_policy" : @1,
                             @"cc_lang_pref" : @"ja"
                             };
```

However the subtitles still do not appear full screen which is what I need. In the middle of the inline video playing the subtitles will appear until right when I change to full screen mode they disappear. They reappear again going back to inline. How do I get them to appear in fullscreen mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google have an API to youtube videos, are you using it?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: No I'm not. Thanks for the heads up though. I might have to change to this if I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the Captions are only available for Youtube API version 2. Captions for a video can only only be created, retrieved, modified and deleted by the owner of the video. To perform these operations for a video. you must submit authenticated API requests for which the video's owner is the logged-in user. API requests for caption operations must contain a properly formatted Authentication header.

Please migrate your application to API version 3. You may use '*i18nLanguage*'. It identifies an application language that the Youtube website supports. The application language can also be referred to as a UI language.

You may use this as your reference:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the help. Subtitles were already made for the video. I should be able to display subtitles automatically without having to own the video. I can do this on the computer and now figured out how to do it programmatically with an in line video. However the subtitles disappear when it is full screen.

Comment: @Casper can you please add an answer description how did you get the subtitle to work? 

I'm using this API and not sure what to do with the response. Can't find a way to handle it. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download